# Firebase random crash

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Messaging, Storage, Database and Crash reporting. Once in a while project randomly crashes and I get something like this:

> EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION
>
> 1  CoreFoundation __exceptionPreprocess + 1245624
>
> 2 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 34136
>
> 3 CoreFoundation -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 1274468
>
> 4 CoreFoundation ***forwarding*** + 1262188
>
> 5 CoreFoundation _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 186376
>
> **6 Flowwow -[FSnapshotHolder updateSnapshot:withNewSnapshot:] (FSnapshotHolder.m:35)**
>
> **7 Flowwow -[FRepo updateInfo:withValue:] (FRepo.m:406)**
>
> **8 Flowwow -[FRepo deferredInit] (FRepo.m:179)**
>
> 9 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 4600
>
> 10 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout + 4536
>
> 11 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 62424
>
> 12 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_queue_invoke + 18848
>
> 13 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 63700
>
> 14 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 70472
>
> 15 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 69800
>
> 16 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_wqthread + 4764
>
> 17 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread + 3464

Tried to find people with the same problem, but did not get any results.

Comment: Crashes are seldom random. Please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it contains a lot of useful hints on getting help).

Comment: It would be helpful, if you posted what your `FRepo` does and specifically what happens in your `updateInfo:withValue:`.

Comment: @Michal It is the part of the Firebase framework, I don't know what does it do and when it is called

Comment: @Edward you're right, my apologies - it slipped out. Could you then please share any piece of code that could lead to this? We can't help you based on this vague stack trace.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. did u figure out what's causing this? thanks!

Comment: @ordinaryman09 nope, still no idea what caused it

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It is just standard Firebase inits and code from Google tutorials. I didn't call anything from the Firebase at the time crash happened (in the AppDelegate). And looks like ordinaryman09 has the same issue.

Comment: What version of Firebase and FirebaseDatabase are you using? The line numbers don't match with the 4.x version - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Database/Core/FSnapshotHolder.m

Comment: Issue filed at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/281

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thanks, should've done that myself back then. The problem is still actual

Comment: I am also getting the same crash with Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[FListenProvider updateChild:withNewChild:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c0220900

Comment: @Er.Khatri try updating pods. It may help